# Handset and Tablet are using mdpi resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am learning the android UI design. I created a sample app for 7 " Tablet and Handset. I am using same layout for both, but styles and drawable resources are placed in appropriate folder like below,

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for xhigh density
```

But both my 5" `moto g handset` and  7" `Lenovo A7-30 3G Tablet` are using the same drawable-mdpi image.

Created two `LinearLayout` under a `RelativeLayout` with equal weight and placed two different image as background for `LinearLayout`.

The UI in `Handset` looks correct and in `Tablet` the `LinearLayout` are not filled by Image and images are occupied in center of `LinearLayout`,thus remaining white space are seen at both side of the images in `LinearLayout`.

Image attached for clear understanding.

[image]

Please help me in fixing this. Please guide me how to make android to use appropriate drawable for `Handset` and `Tablet`.

Comment: Screen *size* has nothing to do with screen *density*. "placed two different image as background for LinearLayout" -- then do not do that, or deal with the fact that not all screens have the same aspect ratio. This is no different than dealing with different window resolutions in desktop or Web apps.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo tablet has ~170 ppi pixel density, so yeah, mdpi at best (nothing wrong here).

To separate resources, see [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), like `drawable-sw600dp` for example.